# How to do binary search for intervals

Tags: c++, search, binary-search

let's say i have an array of pairs of intervals ex. v = {(1,4), (5,10), (11,13), (14,25)}

Now let's say I have number 20 and i want to split the pair in which is 20, or I want to remove the pair (14,25) and to add new two pair - (14,20) and (21, 25). How can I do this in c++, or only how can I search over those intervals and find in which intervals is the number 20.

My idea is to create vector of pairs where I'm going to keep my intervals, but I don't know how to split the interval, and I must do it in log time, so I must use binary search.

Comment: Yes, we can use anything that cpp allows

Comment: I'm trying to write binary search but since i'm not that experienced i don't know how to binary-search the intervals and i don't know which data structure allows me to remove each element from it.

Comment: Does the insert also have to be O(log(n))?

Comment: Yes because N can go up to 100 000 and time limit is 1 second, btw i solved for searching i just can search the first members of the pairs for lowerbound and then upper bound the second member.

Comment: @someone123123: I might be mistaken, but I don't think you can realize both - log(n) lookup and insertion with a vector unless you accept an unreasonable amount of space overhead.

Answer (score 0):

to search in this case use

```
std::upper_bound() or std::lower_bound()
```

to get the index of interval you want to change and proceed. I solved a similar question on codeforces but in that i just wanted to tell the index where the number falls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `std::lower_bound` as @karan suggests; search is in log time but not the insertion if you use vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > input = { {1,4}, {5,10}, {11,13}, {14,25} };
  struct LessInterval {
    bool operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& fst, const std::pair<int, int>& snd)
      {  return fst.second < snd.first; }
  };
  int key = 20;

  // lower_bound uses a dichotomic search in log_2(N)
  auto locateIter = std::lower_bound(input.begin(), input.end(),
      std::make_pair(key, key), LessInterval());
  if (locateIter != input.end()) {
    // modifications on vector can be linear in N; you can consider std::set instead 
    if (locateIter->first <= key && key <= locateIter->second) {
      if (key == locateIter->first) {
        if (locateIter->second == key)
          input.erase(locateIter);
        else
          locateIter->first = key+1;
      }
      else if (key == locateIter->second)
        locateIter->second = key-1;
      else {
        int second = locateIter->second;
        locateIter->second = key-1;
        input.insert(locateIter+1, std::make_pair(key+1, second));
      };
    }
  };

  std::cout << '{';
  bool isFirst = true;
  for(const auto& interval : input) {
    if (!isFirst)
      std::cout << ", ";
    std::cout << '(' << interval.first << ',' << interval.second << ')';
    isFirst = false;
  };
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insertion into a sorted array data structure cannot be faster than O(N), so you'll need something else such as a tree, i.e. `std::set` or `std::map`. These classes have sorting and searching built-in. Their members `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are suitable for finding intervals.

There are a few approaches to representing the intervals in the tree. You can define your own `class interval` or you can use `std::pair`. The easiest way is to use `std::map<int, int>` which is a tree of `std::pair<int, int>` sorted by the first member. I'll suggest a lookup table where the interval upper limits are the keys and the interval lower limits are the values.

`map::upper_bound` takes a number and returns (an iterator to) the first entry which is greater than it. This works well with half-open intervals: Instead of recording the closed interval [14, 25] which goes from 14 to 25 inclusive, use the half-open interval [14, 26) which goes from 14 to 26 non-inclusive. When you search for 25, `upper_bound` will see 26 and return the correct entry.

```
intervals[ 26 ] = 14; // Insert interval [14, 25]

intervals[ 21 ] = 14; // Insert interval [14, 20]
intervals[ 26 ] = 21; // Cut [14, 25] down to [21, 25]
```

Keep in mind that this strategy won't check that the given number is greater than the lower bound of the range, so you'll check that manually after calling `upper_bound`.

```
typedef std::map< int, int > interval_set;
typedef std::pair< const int, int > interval; // {one greater than top, bottom}

bool split_interval( interval_set & s, int p ) {
    interval_set::iterator it = s.upper_bound( p );
    if ( p < it->second ) return false; // Interval doesn't exist. Bail out.

    s.insert( interval{ p + 1, it->second } ); // Insert a new lower-part interval.
    it->second = p; // Cut the lower part from the existing interval.
    return true;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd30949018cb4a00